# PostGIS SQL NOT EXISTS Statements?

Tags: postgresql, sql, database

I'm trying to query my PostGIS database for ID of people who did X but did not do Y. I've attempted the query below, but it does not return any results. I'm very new to SQL so I may be overlooking something. Any thoughts? Thanks for your help.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2
ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
WHERE Table1.Date = '2008-11-04'
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2
    ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
    WHERE Table1.Date = '2012-11-06')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the ID field is what uniquely identifies the person. BTW, really bad to use * especially since Table1 and TAble2 have at least ID in common.

```
SELECT Table1.*
   FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2
      ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
      WHERE Table1.Date = '2008-11-04'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT Y.ID
    FROM Table1 As Y
    WHERE Y.ID = Table1.ID  AND Y.Date = '2012-11-06');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! As a newby I definitely appreciate all of the help that this website as given me. Always someone willing to point me in the right direction. I just ran this query and it appears to be working. I know, I know, I should get away from using * but I'm still in the mindset of "omgggg i need all of the data i can get!!" :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the magic in table2 is all about.  However, your x looks like `'2008-11-04'` and y looks like `'2012-11-06'`.

If your dates have a time component in them, then you may be failing to match on date i.e. 2011-11-06 may have a time value of 00:00:00 or midnight while the dates in your table have 2011-11-06 16:35:33. Those two dates are not equal.

I know that you are struggling to get going with sql but I concur with @LR1234567 that *, splat is an idea to get away from eventually.

```
SELECT *
  FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2
    ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
 WHERE Table1.Date  = '2008-11-04'
   AND Table1.Date != '2012-11-06'
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! As I mentioned in my comment above, I really appreciate all of the help I've received from users of this website as I venture into SQL, javascript, etc. Turns out this query returns basically two sets of data - it includes all of the people who match 2008-11-04 and all of the people who don't match 2012-11-06. The query from @LR1234567 seems to be working - it returns only the people who both match 2008-11-04 and don't match 2012-11-06.

Comment: I take that as a wif!  ;-)